# design regex for particular dataset

Tags: javascript, python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

[The image contains the example data set i want to design a regex which will give me only Id and title from the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfxVc.jpg)

e.g.

15011721827:52352403:War of the League of the Indies
52352403 is the ID for the article. War of the League of the Indies is the title for the article.

i want to extract the ID and title pairs from the given text file

Comment: read file line by line and match with below regex
`[0-9]{10,}[:][0-9]{8}[:][a-z]+` 

and then  
`let a = "15011721827:52352403:War of the League of the Indies".split(':');`
and use a[1] & a[2] to collect id & name of article

Comment: Please don't post pictures. We have a nice formatting system for questions. You can type that stuff out so we don't have to navigate to an image to help you. Also this is not a solution site. Have you tried anything yet? if so please post it.

Comment: @PrAtikLochawalaI want to solve with the only regular expression without using split

Comment: because if we split at " : " it will be inappropriate because some titles also contain " :" in their names

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ([0-9]+)[:]([0-9]+)[:](.*)\n
> ```

Capturing Groups   ([0-9]+)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9

[:] matches the character  ':'

•   3rd Capturing Group 
(.*) Matches any character (except for line terminators)

•   \n matches a line-feed

```
import re

text = open('example.txt').read()
pattern = r'([0-9]+)[:]([0-9]+)[:](.*)\n'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
for match in regex.finditer(text):
      result = ("{},{}".format(match.group(2),match.group(3)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, could you also explain in words why you chose this particular solution? For newcomers to regular expressions, it would particularly help how the regular expression is built up.

Comment: Capturing Groups   ([0-9]+)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9  

[:] matches the character  ':'

• 3rd Capturing Group 
(.*) Matches any character (except for line terminators)

• \n matches a line-feed

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, you can do it simply using `split()` that divide your string when matching double points :

```js
var text = "1234567890:12312312:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var splitted = text.split(":");

console.log("id : " + splitted[1]);
console.log("Title : " + splitted[2]);
```

Using pure regex, you can do it with this one : `([0-9]{10,})[:]([0-9]{8})[:]([a-zA-Z ]+)`

```
Group 1 : 1234567890
Group 2 (ID) : 12312312 
Group 3 (Title) : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

The first group will detect 10 numbers from 0 to 9.
The second group will detect 8 numbers from 0 to 9.
The third group will detect a to Z and spaces.

Working example : https://regex101.com/r/3TudrD/1

Answer (score 0):

Because in your dataset you can have in the Title a `:` it's better to use RegEx like bellow

```
15011721827:52352403:War of the League of the Indies
9428491646:27687104:Deepwater Pathfinder
3524782652:4285058:Wikipedia:Articles for deletion/Joseph Prymak
2302538806:1870985:Cardinal Infante Ferdinand`
```

On the Third line there are a `:` which separate Wikipedia to the rest of the Title, if you use `split` function you will have an array with 4 instead of 3 part. To avoid that kind of issue, I choose to use regular expresssion

```js
var pattern = /^(\d+):(\d+):(.+)$/
var data = "15011721827:52352403:War of the League of the Indies"
var matches = data.match(pattern)
console.log(matches)

// matches[0] = "15011721827:52352403:War of the League of the Indies"
// matches[1] = "15011721827"
// matches[2] = "52352403"
// matches[3] = "War of the League of the Indies"
```